# Passing a List<String> to a MYSQL Stored Procedure in Java Spring?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, stored-procedures, spring-mvc

Is it possible to call this in Spring using SimpleJdbcCall and pass a List as the variable?

MYSQL

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE example(IN list ?)
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM exampleTable WHERE exampleColumn IN (list)
    END //
```

Java

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(source).withProcedureName("example");
SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().
                              addValue(?, ?);
Map<String, Object> out = jdbcCall.execute(in);
```

Comment: That's not possible. You should have to build a query inside your procedure and execute it dynamically.

Comment: You can do list.toString() and remove the opening and closing square brackets, and pass the result to your stored procedure.